# CMake External Project not Downloading

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake 3.5.1 with CLion, and I am attempting to download and install an external project from a URL.  My CMakeLists.txt include:

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXTERNAL ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external)
ExternalProject_Add(eigen_test
        PREFIX ${EXTERNAL}/eigen
        DOWNLOAD_DIR ${EXTERNAL}/eigen/download
        SOURCE_DIR ${EXTERNAL}/eigen/src
        BINARY_DIR ${EXTERNAL}/eigen/build
        INSTALL_DIR ${EXTERNAL}/eigen/install
        URL http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.2.4.tar.gz
        URL_MD5 4d0d77e06fef87b4fcd2c9b72cc8dc55
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd <BINARY_DIR> && cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$<INSTALL_DIR> <SOURCE_DIR>
        )
```

When building, this [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xcfC.png) is is created inside `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/`

Although the cmake files exist to download and extract the project, these actions never occur.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Although the cmake files exist to download and extract the project, these actions never occur.` - So, what happens when you build the project?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see a reason to pollute your project by downloading and building the library in `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`, I always do that in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`.
2. The `eigen` library uses `CMakeLists.txt`, it will work seamlessly as external project, you don't have to extensively configure each step. So `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` can be removed and the install prefix set with `CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...`

This is the simplified and working configuration:

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXTERNALS_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external)
ExternalProject_Add(eigen_test
    PREFIX ${EXTERNALS_DIR}
    URL http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.2.4.tar.gz
    URL_MD5 4d0d77e06fef87b4fcd2c9b72cc8dc55
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNALS_DIR}/installed
    )
```

How to use the library:

1. Add `${EXTERNALS_DIR}/installed/include` to include directories
2. Build the `eigen_test` target